# Build one image and use it for multiple services in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'd like to run two apps off the same image built using Docker Compose. Sounds easy enough, but apparently, I'm missing something important:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  app1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile_inline: |
        FROM ruby:3.2-alpine
        (...)
        RUN bundle install
    image: app-image:latest
    command: "bundle exec puma"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    ports:
      - "80:9292"
  app2:
    image: app-image:latest
    command: "bundle exec puma"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    ports:
      - "81:9292"
```

Building works fine and finishes without any warnings or errors:

```
$ docker compose build

#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver
#1 [app1 internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context:
#1 transferring context: 2B done
#1 ...
#2 [app1 internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
(...)
#10 [app1 6/6] RUN bundle install
#10 2.105 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
#10 2.137 Fetching bundler 2.4.21
#10 2.250 Installing bundler 2.4.21
#10 3.246 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
#10 5.330 Resolving dependencies...
#10 5.456 Fetching crass 1.0.6
(...)
#11 [app1] exporting to image
#11 exporting layers
#11 exporting layers 4.8s done
#11 writing image sha256:e1720a10482b609ccb990c8c656c8d18295f39a6576f87c54c4780d4060058e4 0.0s done
#11 naming to docker.io/library/app-image:latest 0.1s done
#11 DONE 4.9s
time="2023-11-25T13:04:30Z" level=warning msg="buildx: git was not found in the system. Current commit information was not captured by the build"
```

Upping the services, however, does the following:

```
$ docker compose up

app1 Pulling 
app2 Pulling 
app1 Warning 
app2 Error 
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver
#1 [app1 internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 296B done
#1 DONE 0.3s
#2 [app1 internal] load .dockerignore
(...)
```

So the build runs again and when finished, both services are running.

Any idea why the rebuild happens there? Also, `app1 Warning` and `app2 Error` are not very helpful, is there a way to get more details?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't get this to work with `dockerfile_inline`, but it works if I move this into a classic `Dockerfile` and then:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  app1:
    build: .
    image: app-image:latest
    command: "bundle exec puma"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    ports:
      - "80:9292"
  app2:
    build: .
    image: app-image:latest
    command: "bundle exec puma"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    ports:
      - "81:9292"
```

So, half the answer only... just in case someone knows what's really going on here.